# Windows 10 compare restart versus shutdown

Tags: windows-10, boot, reboot

If you want you windows 10 machine to do a 'clean boot' with no current application or windows OS state carried over to the next session which do you choose?

You may be new to the differences between restart and shutdown/power on Windows 10 and may not have the keyword "fast startup" in mind as it does not appear in the Windows 10 menu, or in 'type here to search'.
You may also be on Windows 10 enterprise and cannot see all the settings detailed in
[The Pros and Cons of Windows 10’s “Fast Startup” Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/%20%22The%20Pros%20and%20Cons%20of%20Windows%2010%E2%80%99s%20%E2%80%9CFast%20Startup%E2%80%9D%20Mode)

In this case you will miss the excellent details in
[Script to turn fast startup on/off](https://superuser.com/questions/1265492/script-to-turn-fast-startup-on-off)

Answer (score 0):

I found a well known search engine returning the wrong answer 1st, relating to Windows 7, so I've added my research content here.

In short, choose **restart** for a cleaner reboot (slower).

from Britechguy
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/625963/details-of-shut-down-vs-restart-please/

> I believe the advent of Fast Startup/Fast Boot was with Windows 8 and it definitely carries over to Windows 10.  It is enabled by default.
>
> If Fast Start/Boot is enabled then a Shut Down is not a full, complete shut down but is an abbreviated form of hibernation and uses a hibernation file.  In true, full hibernation when the system is being shut down a file image of the OS state as well as the application program states are written out to disc for retrieval when the machine is turned back on.  When Fast Startup/Boot is enabled, the hibernation only includes the OS state, not the application program states, but these are still written out to disc for retrieval when the system is fired up again.
>
> By contrast, Restart intentionally saves absolutely nothing regarding the OS state or the applications states.  After shutting down it reloads the OS from scratch from the disc drive files that make up the OS.
>
> To me, the above architecture is precisely the opposite of what I think a default shut down an restart would and should logically do (and actually did do, at least with regard to a shut down, in Windows 7 and earlier).  However, once you know this you are able to make the correct choice for what you're trying to achieve.
>
> If you go to the Power Options dialog if Control Panel, activate the "Choose what the power button does" link and then, on the page that comes up, the "Change settings that are currently unavailable" link the checkboxes for the four power state tweaks will become accessible.  You can add or remove Hibernate or Sleep from the Power menu, tweak how/when the lock screen appears, but most importantly you can choose to turn Fast Startup/Boot off.  If you do this, then choosing to shut down does an actual full shutdown with no abbreviated hibernation component involved.  When you power up again the OS must load completely from disc like it would for a Restart.  I disabled this option long ago because I didn't see that big a difference in boot time and, more importantly, when I do a shut down I want everything about the current system state to be tossed and a fresh reload of the full OS when I start the machine next time.

Comment: You can also disable fast shutdown either all the time. Also you can do it once by holding shift while shutting down. When you do this, its the same as restart, except the computer goes off and has to be turned on again. There is plenty of information here on SuperUser though...